# LINQ error type DBNull column

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, linq

I am querying a datagridview and it works great unless one of the cells has nothing (dbnull). How to over come this?

Exceptions: Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'DBNull'.

```
Dim query = From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows _
            Where row.Cells(SelectedColumnIndex).Value = filter _
            And row.Visible = False _
            Select row Distinct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.Equals()` method to compare values in which one may be null.  Example:

```
Dim query = From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows _
        Where row.Cells(SelectedColumnIndex).Value.Equals(filter) _
        And !(row.Visible) _
        Select row Distinct
```

Or if both may be null, you can use the base `Object.Equals()` method to compare:

```
Dim query = From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows _
            Where Object.Equals(row.Cells(SelectedColumnIndex).Value, filter) _
            And !(row.Visible) _
            Select row Distinct
```

Comment: Solved the problem for me too!